Alternative to using cards or tables for displaying different data/info
The problem
Our product currently uses a lot of data tables to show information to our users. We also have a lot of metrics and numerical data that we also display that is often clickable that filters the table below or takes users to a new screen.
These additional points of info are typically placed in cards. But we can often end of with a lot of individual cards on the screen that is overloading and confusing our users.
Is there any other pattern to display small points of data rather than cards or tables?
Included an image to hopefully help explain the issue.
Thanks


Are each horizontal stack co-related between them ? For example if I select the card one on the first row that will make the second row appear? Can you explain a little more or use a dummy example?

@EmmanuelCuevas In some cases the cards are related to the data grid below, those cards might display the number of 'open tasks' for example and when clicked, would filter the table below showing those open tasks.
In other cases, for example, the cards would display info regarding a banking account; Money in, Money Out, Money owed etc. Then clicking on the card would take users to that page, so it acts as an overview page with snippets of detail on the cards before drilling down further. The use case in reality is a lot more complex however than showing all data together

Thanks for sharing this.
I put your design and comments into a feedback software I like to use. Here are the results; I will share thoughts after --

Categorize Tiles More Intuitively:   Group related tiles into distinct clusters (e.g., "Task Overview," "Financial Summary")
Use subtle visual cues (background shading, borders) to differentiate groupings.   Credit: littlebro.app

As you mentioned, there's information overload. Cards, tables, or graphs are typically the best way to display dense information but it's important to make sure you bundle related information and only show what's important to the user at that time.
The above suggests you combine related tiles together and hide them until the user absolutely needs it. If you've determined that users typically use a certain card more often, you can have those showing by default at the top. Otherwise, grouping tiles together is very important to help with information overload.

Layout:   Implement a grid system for tiles, aiming for a 4x2 or 6x2 layout above your data grid. Ensure the design is responsive for various screen sizes.   Credit: littlebro.app

This builds on top of the bundling of tiles. Make sure your tiles are consistent. When they're different sizes (like the mockup shown) it increases visual clutter and makes it look more messy. Keeping a grid system will also make it easy for your developers to make the tiles responsive.

Multi-functional Tiles: Design tiles with clear visual indicators for their behavior (filtering vs. navigation).   For filter tiles (e.g., "Open Tasks"), include a small filter icon.   For navigation tiles (e.g., "Money In"), use a subtle arrow or "view more" text   Credit: littlebro.app

I thought this one was pretty interesting. It seems like your tiles have different use cases. One navigates while another updates the table below. It'd be nice for the user to immediately know which card does what.
I'd be happy to dive into more details or share more thoughts if needed!

"Crediting" your own site without disclosing your affiliation makes this unacceptable promotion. Please review How to not be a spammer.

I've gotten flagged for putting the credit in as well as leaving the credit out. I'm just genuinely trying to help answer this question. Sure i'm trying to raise awareness but the main goal is to answer the question actionably and thoroughly. Let me know if i'm missing the point here.

@tripleee I would like to propose some way of dealing with this matter from the comments section, so please feel free to provide your input here: https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3478/using-uxse-chat-to-address-concerns-about-use-of-ai-generated-content

@CozyBro as suggested by the community, if you can credit the LLM that is used to generate the content rather than the specific app, that would be more suitable in the interest of avoiding self-promotion while also attributing or disclosing that there is AI generated content (which is not banned if disclosed and credited).
